# Why is this a valid scanf statement to break out of a while loop?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, scanf

Why is this a valid line of code to break out of an infinite `while` loop?

```
if (scanf("%s", word) != 1) break;
```

Comment: What does `scanf` returns?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (scanf("%s", word) != 1) break;
```

`scanf` returns the number of items successfully consumed. This value is used as the left hand operand inside of the expression. Thus, this expression is perfectly valid.

In the following example this value shall be `1` if no I/O error occurred and a string was successfully converted because there is only one item to consume.

I guess this `if` statement is part of a loop whose intention is to read subsequent words from the input until it encounters an `EOF` state for `stdin` or any redirected file used as input because the condition is only then evaluated to `true` (and with that to break out of the surrounding loop) if `EOF` or another `I/O` error has happen as `scanf()` returns `0` in this case.

This shall give you an insight of how this `if` statement is to be evaluated and interpreted.

Comment: EOF is something that happens out-of-band. IOW you don't encounter EOF in the stream,  the stream can enter an EOF state or other error state

Comment: @M.M Better now? I never thought about that intensely. My thought was that `FILE` inserts `EOF` directly into the stream. Well, I have to read about that more. Thank you, too.

Answer (score -1):

The mentioned break statement and its guard is valid but it's lying. Consider the loop

```
while (1) {
   ...
}
```

According to the rules of structured programming the loop should never exit, that is unless the program exits. Rather than using a break statement, a properly structured program should use the return value from the function *scan* as the loop guard, like this:

```
tokenCount = scanf("%s", word);
while (tokenCount == 1) {
    ...
    tokenCount = scanf("%s", word);
}
```

It's also easier to reason about the correctness of a program if expressions do not have side effects; that's why the return value is stored in a variable (with a meaningful name).

Comment: Some people (myself included) prefer an endless loop with a `break` statement to a "proper" loop with an explicit end condition. This makes it easier to move code around at early stages of development. Also, if you have to repeat parts of your code outside the loop just to avoid an endless loop, that's especially ugly.

Comment: Your suggestion is worse due to repeating the same code twice.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: @M.M That's a valid point. However, to my mind the benefit is greater than the cost. The scan statement is not complicated.